# Android: get displayed text from textview in signle line only available

Tags: android, textview

I have single line textview. I am setting string in it. Sometimes full string not possible to display. So I just want that string which is displayed.

```
TextView valueTV = new TextView(context);
//                          valueTV.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MIDDLE);

                        valueTV.setText(list.get(i).getTitle());


                        valueTV.setTag(i);
                            valueTV.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(clr));
                            valueTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(txtclr));
                        if(dt1.equals(startdt))
                        {
                            valueTV.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(txtclr));

                        }else {
                            valueTV.setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        }
                            valueTV.setTypeface(type_thin);
                            valueTV.setId(list.get(i).getId());
                            valueTV.setMaxLines(1);
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            ll.setMargins(0,1,0,0);
                            valueTV.setLayoutParams(ll);
                            valueTV.setOnClickListener(this);
                            lladd.addView(valueTV);
```

For Example

Full String : I am Android Developer
RIght now it displays:

I am And

So How can I get

I am And?

Thanks

Comment: try : `valueTV.setMaxLines(1);`

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I do not want that. I want visible text on the textview. I have already set Max line to 1.

Answer (score 3):

I thanks both @Andriy and Sujith for helping. Mix of both answers worked for me.

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = valueTV.getViewTreeObserver();
                        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onGlobalLayout() {


                                int end = valueTV.getOffsetForPosition(valueTV.getWidth(), 0) + 1;
                        String displayed = valueTV.getText().toString().substring(0, end);

                                System.out.println("i---displayed--" + displayed);
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `getOffsetForPosition()`. For visible text from start something like that:

```
int end = textView.getOffsetForPosition(textView.getWidth(), 0) + 1;
String displayed = textView.getText().toString().substring(0, end);
```

Comment: I am getting end = 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = textView.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                String text = (String) textView.getText().subSequence(0, textView.getLayout().getEllipsisStart(0));
                Log.i(TAG, "Txt: " + text);
            }
        });
```

this gives you the text visible in textview (without three dots)

Comment: I tried thie before. Again I tried.
I get this error.
                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.text.Layout.getEllipsisStart(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Yes, because you called it in onCreate method I guess. It will give this error if the layout is not created. So call it from onResume or after.

Comment: Its inside adapter. Actually its calendar. inside getView

Comment: So you have to use viewtreeObserver to listen for layout complete. See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks it works
But your answer and Andriy's answer mixed answer.

ViewTreeObserver vto = valueTV.getViewTreeObserver();
      vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
       @Override
       public void onGlobalLayout() {


        int end = valueTV.getOffsetForPosition(valueTV.getWidth(), 0) + 1;
      String displayed = valueTV.getText().toString().substring(0, end);

        System.out.println("i---displayed--" + displayed);
       }
      });

Comment: Cool, good mixed answer! Post your new answer as correct answer, so others will also get to know :)